# как можно перехватить вызов метода объекта WebSocket в chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как можно перехватить данные которые передаются к конструктор WebSocket и метод send?

Мой код

```
let WebSocketProxy = new Proxy(window.WebSocket, {
   construct(target, args) {
       console.log(args);
       return new target(...args);
   },
});

window.WebSocket = WebSocketProxy;

console.log(WebSocket);
```

При запуске контент скрипта в консоль выводится "ƒ anonymous()". Если я вызову в консоли

```
console.log(WebSocket);
```

То выведется "ƒ WrappedWebSocket(url, ...args)"

run_at установлен в document_idle

Comment: @Вадим Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky лучше дать ссылку на качественное описание, чем пытаться продублировать источник. а по ссылке было:
    var con = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/WS_server");
con.onopen = function (event) {
};
con.onmessage = function (event) {
};  
con.onclose = function (event) {
};
con.onerror = function (error) {
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const WebSocketProxy = new Proxy(window.WebSocket, {
construct(target, args) {
    console.log(args);

    const instance = new target(...args);

    const openHandler = (event) => {
        console.log('Open', event);
    };

    const messageHandler = (event) => {
        console.log('Message', event);
    };

    const closeHandler = (event) => {
        console.log('Close', event);
        instance.removeEventListener('open', openHandler);
        instance.removeEventListener('message', messageHandler);
        instance.removeEventListener('close', closeHandler);
    };

    instance.addEventListener('open', openHandler);
    instance.addEventListener('message', messageHandler);
    instance.addEventListener('close', closeHandler);

    const sendProxy = new Proxy(instance.send, {
        apply: function(target, thisArg, _args) {
            console.log('Send', _args);
            target.apply(thisArg, _args);
        }
    });

    instance.send = sendProxy;

    return instance;
},
});

window.WebSocket = WebSocketProxy;
```